# What parameters do we need to use for our shopping cart to pull revenue and order ID into Adwords and Kenshoo?

Tags: shopping-cart

We want to track revenue and order ID for Kenshoo and AdWords pixels that are currently placed on our Checkout Success page.  What parameters to we need in order to pull this data into these two platforms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$total = $order->getGrandTotal();
```